# How to code "Not Applicable" in case of Likert Scale Data to calculate correlation coefficient in R

Tags: r, correlation, na

I measured items/questions using  Likert scale (1 to 5) and I was suggested to include "Not Applicable (NA)" optional response apart from the 5 point scale. I think this NA response is not missing value. In this case how can I code NA while calculating correlation coefficients?

I tried to collapse them into trichotomy like:
1 for strongly Disagree/ Disagree/ Not applicable
2 for Neutral
3 for Strongly Agree/ Agree

However, it didn't work as some of the items have only strongly agree and agree that means all the values of that item is 3 and I can not calculate correlation is such case and got NAs.

Comment: Why waste information by triaging your raw data without need? In your case, the effect was immediate: you made at least one of two variables A or B a constant, so no meaningful correlation there (as R correctly reports). Why not assign the central value of your Likert scale to "not available", if you want to keep those, and move on from there. When in doubt, the community over at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ will likely offer on-spot advice for general statistical question (while here's the place to help with implementation specifically in R).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I shall attempt to answer it.

I do not have a reproducible example to work off of, but consider trying this.

I assume your factor levels are in `data$likert_scale <- c(1,2,3,4,5,NA)`

`data %>% mutate(likert_factor = fct_explicit_na(factor(likert_scale, levels=1:5), na_level = "Not Applicable")`

The above code should make the column into a factor, explicitly making the NA data into a level called "Not Applicable".

A more important thing to consider is not to run correlation coefficients with a nominal variable like this, especially if you were to include "NA" as a level, given NA is neither a 0 nor a 6 on a scale.